# Pytorch Change Tensor Dimensions in Neural Net

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, dimensions

how can I make sure, that my Model changes the tensor into the right dimension.
I currently insert a 28*28 tensor and need an output of a 10(linear)tensor
with nn.Linear(28,10) I can change one dimension, but how can I change the other one?

Thanks

I tried:
`nn.Flatten torch.unsqueece tensor.reshape Conv2DTranspose.`

Comment: It is not very clear to me what is your intention here. Do you mean for an input `(28,28)` tensor, after some manipulation by fully connected layers `nn.Linear`, return a tensor with shape `(10,)`?

Answer (score 0):

There are infinity of possibilities.
An easy way is just to flatten it first and then connect it to a linear layer. Like this:

```
...
x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
x = self.fc(x) #where self.fc is nn.Linear(28*28, 10)
....
```